# Maven dependencies issues in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm creating a new project and the pom.xml file with the dependencies is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <parent>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
                </parent>
                <groupId>theo.jpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <name>example</name>
                <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

                <properties>
                    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                </properties>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

       </project>
```

However 3 of the dependencies seem to have some problems. Why is this happening? How can I correct them?

[image: Maven screen shot]

**UPDATE**

I added this **application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

And get no error when I am doing the maven install.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< theo.jpa:demo >----------------------------
[INFO] Building example 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/Java Spring Tutorials/spring-boot-spring-mvc-bootstrap/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests
17:24:41.733 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:41.742 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
17:24:41.756 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
17:24:41.787 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
17:24:41.991 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
17:24:42.007 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]: class path resource [theo/jpa/demo/ExampleApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
17:24:42.011 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]: class path resource [theo/jpa/demo/ExampleApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
17:24:42.011 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
17:24:42.013 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]: ExampleApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
17:24:42.135 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.349 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/Java Spring Tutorials/spring-boot-spring-mvc-bootstrap/target/classes/theo/jpa/demo/ExampleApplication.class]
17:24:42.351 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplication for test class theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests
17:24:42.600 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]: using defaults.
17:24:42.603 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
17:24:42.742 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@692f203f, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@48f2bd5b, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@7b2bbc3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@a1153bc, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@1aafa419, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@47eaca72, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@55141def, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@55182842, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@3270d194, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@235834f2, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@5656be13, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@4218d6a3]
17:24:42.758 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.760 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.762 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.767 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.787 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.788 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.862 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@4afcd809 testClass = ExampleApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@175c2241 testClass = ExampleApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1fc2b765, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@22eeefeb, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@10a035a0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@31f924f5], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
17:24:42.870 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.870 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests]
17:24:42.961 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

2019-01-03 17:24:58.582  INFO 1289 --- [           main] theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests    : Starting ExampleApplicationTests on Theodosioss-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 1289 (started by theodosiostziomakas in /Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/Java Spring Tutorials/spring-boot-spring-mvc-bootstrap)
2019-01-03 17:24:58.584  INFO 1289 --- [           main] theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-03 17:24:59.422  INFO 1289 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-01-03 17:24:59.475  INFO 1289 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 23ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-01-03 17:24:59.955  INFO 1289 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$819e6851] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-03 17:25:00.261  INFO 1289 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-01-03 17:25:00.841  INFO 1289 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-01-03 17:25:00.931  INFO 1289 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2019-01-03 17:25:01.090  INFO 1289 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2019-01-03 17:25:01.092  INFO 1289 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-01-03 17:25:01.346  INFO 1289 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-01-03 17:25:01.547  INFO 1289 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-01-03 17:25:01.884  INFO 1289 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-03 17:25:02.823  INFO 1289 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-03 17:25:02.903  WARN 1289 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-01-03 17:25:03.305  INFO 1289 --- [           main] theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests    : Started ExampleApplicationTests in 20.327 seconds (JVM running for 22.223)
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 21.899 s - in theo.jpa.demo.ExampleApplicationTests
2019-01-03 17:25:03.437  INFO 1289 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-03 17:25:03.438  INFO 1289 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-01-03 17:25:03.440  INFO 1289 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-01-03 17:25:03.478  INFO 1289 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0:jar (default-jar) @ demo ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/Java Spring Tutorials/spring-boot-spring-mvc-bootstrap/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ demo ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ demo ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/Java Spring Tutorials/spring-boot-spring-mvc-bootstrap/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/theodosiostziomakas/.m2/repository/theo/jpa/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/Java Spring Tutorials/spring-boot-spring-mvc-bootstrap/pom.xml to /Users/theodosiostziomakas/.m2/repository/theo/jpa/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.386 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-03T17:25:05+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I still have the same issues with my dependencies.

Comment: Well I created project with your pom.xml dependencies and it works so the problem is somewhere else. Try to clean maven dependencies folder and let maven download them again

Comment: @RafałSokalski. I went to Lifecycle->clean but still nothing.

Comment: what exactly is "some problems"? Whats the error message for those dependencies?

Comment: @f1sh Please look at the logcat which I just put in my original question.

Comment: You need to read the error message. It explains what is wrong, and explains the possible ways of fixing it. It's English. it means something. Also read the relevant documentation, which always helps.

Comment: It looks like you didn't configure database connection

Comment: @RafałSokalski Ok then. So how to configure the db connection?

Comment: In application.properties you have to put information about database connetion. More details [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-oracle-example/) Look at point nr. 4

Comment: Because you show 0 effort in trying to solve it by yourself. Apparently you didn't read the error message, didn't read the documentation, didn't try anything to solve the problem by yourself. The main reason, shown in the tooltip when you hver the button is "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: @JBNizet What error are you talking about? Database connection?

Comment: Yes: the error message that is listed in your question.

Comment: @f1sh Please look at my update. I did the database set up (mysql in my case) get no errors when I don "mvn install" but still 3 dependencies are highlited as red :(

Comment: @JBNizet Please look at my update.

Comment: @JBNizet Please look at my update.

Comment: So you've fixed the issues. Congrats.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for uprating my question too!

Comment: @Theo I am assuming your question is about the IDE showing maven error. Try clicking the "Reimport all Maven Projects" icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Spring boot's [Connection to a Production Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) reference about adding datasource properties

> DataSource configuration is controlled by external configuration properties in spring.datasource.*. For example, you might declare the following section in application.properties:
>
> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
> spring.datasource.username=dbuser
> spring.datasource.password=dbpass
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> ```